# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided after github push

Tags: javascript, git, view

The app/website I was working on with a friend of mine was working and I made changes. After pushing changes (git origin master), my code broke and I got this error: 
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Very confused on what is causing this. 
My friend git cloned the origin master and the code also broke on him.
Here is the git repo: 
https://github.com/anotherjung/learnMEAN17_fullstore

I compared my code with another MEAN/Javascript project, and I can't spot the difference.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have made two commits (first [4fbc5a4](https://github.com/anotherjung/learnMEAN17_fullstore/commit/4fbc5a44b7cbd60a9a4269d6dbf92341ceea7ed0), then [95fa49b](https://github.com/anotherjung/learnMEAN17_fullstore/commit/95fa49b1d0a5153515bc145212ebe638be3eee3a)).

Try and checkout the first one:

```
git clone https://github.com/anotherjung/learnMEAN17_fullstore
git checkout @~
```

(you will be in detached HEAD mode, but that is just for testing)

See if that first commit works.

If not, checkout its parent (commit [63ea1ad](https://github.com/anotherjung/learnMEAN17_fullstore/commit/63ea1ad7521f47f56e9ef0487b0257fea48837e0)): `git checkout @~`, and check that it does work.
Try to apply your changes bits by bits, to spot what introduces a breaking change.